# luma.gl Reference error: window is not defined

Tags: window, referenceerror, deck.gl

One of the tasks for my current project is trying to find the source of the following console error:

[image]

I have looked through all the references to the window object as well as the luma.gl library but can't seem to find where the issue is originating.  It doesn't seem to break anything but is more of an annoyance when debugging as it pops up over 20 times in a row whenever the page is refreshed.  Here are the versions of Deck.gl and Luma.gl from package.json:

[image]

Just want to know if anyone has encountered this before and how you might have fixed it.  Thank you.

I have eliminated all calls to the window object within the project to no avail and have looked through polyfill-context.js inside the @luma.gl library with no luck either.